# Accessor decorator and instanced class context

Tags: javascript, typescript, decorator

I cannot figure out how to bind the instanced class context in class accessor decorator. My class in a nutshell is:

```
class A {
    protected persistProperty(a, b) {
        // ...
    }
}

class C extends A {
    @validatorTest
    public set coolStuff(email: string) {
        this.persistProperty('company.email', email);
    }
}
```

The decorator:

```
function validatorTest(
    target: any,
    propertyKey: string,
    descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<string>
) {
    const oldSet = descriptor.set;

    descriptor.set = (value: string) => {
        if (value && !value.match(...)) {
            throw new Error();
        }

        oldSet(value);
    }
}
```

Now the problem arises when I use the accessor:

```
let foo = new C();

c.coolStuff = 'a@b.c';
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'persistProperty' of undefined
```

So, as I mentioned, it seems the context of instanced class is not bind to the decorator. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, found out the issue myself after all.. apparently, you cannot use arrow syntax in descriptor overrides. So, this works as intended (also thanks to Madara's answer):

```
function validatorTest(
    target: any,
    propertyKey: string,
    descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<string>
) {
    const oldSet = descriptor.set;

    descriptor.set = function(value: string) {
        if (value && !value.match(...)) {
            throw new Error();
        }

        oldSet.call(this, value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a TypeScript issue, you've lost your `this` context by calling `oldSet()` without a `this`.

Educated guess: Try `oldSet.call(this, value)`

Comment: <strike>@madara, in this example, is there an easy way to _forward_ parameters.</strike>